# Style layer.editing in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

I'm working on getting the events of deletion and edition outside the box of leaflet, meaning using buttons binded to events instead of the drawtoolbar.

The editing button calls layer.editing.enable();

What I've done earlier is style the polygones under editition mode using an extend of the class Edit:

```
L.Edit.PolyVerticesEdit = L.Edit.PolyVerticesEdit.extend({
            options: {
                icon: new L.DivIcon({
                    className: 'edit-marker',
                    iconSize: [28, 28],
                    html: '<i class="fa fa-circle fa-2x fa-circle"></i>'
                })
            }
        });
```

So, when I do an edit using the drawtoolbar, the shapes are styled correctly. However, when I use the button( layer.editing.enable()) the shapes are under default styles. So my conclusion was that draw Toolbar doesn't class the same method as layer.editing.enable(); from here comes my question.

How can I style the polygon vertices using layer.editing.enable() ?

[image]
Case of using buttons

[image]
case of using toolbar